# Taking a csv list and iterating through it with a sequence

Tags: ansible, iteration

I have a playbook which takes a input list of comma-separated values from the user:

`a,b,c,d`

And turns it into a list using `split` (`extra_hosts` is the variable that stores the input from the user)

```yaml
- name: Generate hosts list
  set_fact:
    hosts_list: []

- name: Build hosts list
  set_fact:
    san_list: "{{ hosts_list + [host] }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: host
  with_items: "{{ extra_hosts | split(',') }}"
```

Now this works fine so far. If I `debug` at this point, I get:

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
    ]
}
```

What I want to do now is to output into a file, the list in the format:

```yaml
Host 1: a
Host 2: b
Host 3: c
Host 4: d
```

I can easily iterate over the list and output using this:

```yaml
- name: Append hosts to file
  lineinfile:
    path: "hosts.conf"
    line: "Host: {{ host }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: host
  with_items: "{{ hosts_list }}"
```

However, this outputs (obviously) as:

```yaml
Host: a
Host: b
Host: c
Host: d
```

But I don't think I can iterate with two variables (the second being the [sequence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/lookup/sequence.html) module), so I can't do something like:

```yaml
- name: Append hosts to file
  lineinfile:
    path: "hosts.conf"
    line: "Host: {{ host }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: host
  with_items: "{{ hosts_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: id
  with_sequence: start=1
```

I was thinking maybe somehow converting the list into a dict, so I'd end up with something like:

```json
{id: 1, host: "a"},
{id: 2, host: "b"},
{id: 3, host: "c"},
{id: 4, host: "d"}
```

Then I can then just use something like `{{ item.id }}` and `{{ item.host }}` to write those out -- but to build the dict, I would still need to iterate with two pointers -- an incremental value, and the pointer within the list.

Is there way I can do this, and what is the best/correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, the task below will be skipped if *extra_hosts* is not defined

```yaml
    - copy:
        dest: hosts.conf
        content: |-
          {% for i in extra_hosts.split(',') %}
          Host {{ loop.index }}: {{ i }}
          {% endfor %}
      when: extra_hosts|d('')|length > 0
```

If the variable *extra_hosts* is defined (e.g. `-e extra_hosts='a,b,c,d'`) the task will create the file *hosts.conf*

```sh
shell> cat hosts.conf 
Host 1: a
Host 2: b
Host 3: c
Host 4: d
```

Comment: What does the `{% .. %}` mean?

Comment: See [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#).

Comment: Ahhhh... This is like Helm stuff. So I could put this inside the config file and use the `template` module?

Comment: Right. You'll get the same result when you put *content* into a template file *hosts.conf.j2* and use *template* module.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for opening my eyes on a part of Ansible I had never thought to use until now

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question

> ... the list in the format ...

you may take advantage from [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

   LIST: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

  tasks:

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "Host {{ ansible_loop.index }}: {{ LIST[ansible_loop.index0] }}"
    loop: "{{ LIST }}"
    loop_control:
      label: "{{ item }}"
      extended: yes
```

results into an output of

```
TASK [Show result] ***********
ok: [localhost] => (item=a) =>
  msg: 'Host 1: a'
ok: [localhost] => (item=b) =>
  msg: 'Host 2: b'
ok: [localhost] => (item=c) =>
  msg: 'Host 3: c'
ok: [localhost] => (item=d) =>
  msg: 'Host 4: d'
```

Comment: Oooo. This one is much easier to read. Thank you :)

Comment: @BlenderFox, regarding your question in the other answer "_What does the {% .. %} mean?_", it is about Jinja2 Templating and creating in one step exactly the file you were looking for.

Comment: Yes, I will accept the answer on that one, but I like this one also, as it's much more readable